# React render when props change

Tags: reactjs, redux, render, react-props

I am trying to render my component when props changes only, unfortunately, it keeps rendering even when the props is unchanged, my codes is as follow:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps,prevState){

    if(prevProps.data !== this.props.data){
        this.props.getData(userID)
      }
   }


    render(){
   //console.log('render') infinite rendering even when this.props.data is unchanged 
       return(
          <Mycomponent data={this.props.data}/>
      )
  }

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    data: state.api.data,

})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Component1)
```

Comment: You should make sure that no data has been updated.

Rendering is also not a problem as long as you do it well because React has optimized it well. Even so, if you want to improve it as long as it's not more expensive than not doing it, you could try to do it as a class:

- React.memo ( https://es.reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo )
- Transfer the component to PureComponent ( https://es.reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactpurecomponent )

Comment: which version of react you are using?

Comment: react version 16.8.3

Comment: this.props.data contains quite complex data structures

Comment: what is happening getData function? if you are updating data in getData function then your component will go in infinite loop.

Comment: I am fetching data from API by getData and the data is unchanged, I want to render my component only when the data is changed from the API, in short I want to Listen when this.props.data is changed

Comment: can you please add code of its parent component as well. want to see how data is passed to this component?

Comment: the data is being passed from redux

Comment: ok. can you paste that code?

Comment: I did paste at the bottom

Comment: Wouldn't [shouldComponentUpdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate) be enough for this?

Answer (score 1):

I believe using a PureComponent instead of a Component will ensure that the component only renders when it receives new information. This is how I would do it:

```
import React, { PureComponent } from "react";
import Mycomponent from "./Mycomponent";

export default class WrapperComponent extends PureComponent {
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps,prevState){

    if(prevProps.data !== this.props.data){
        this.props.getData(userID)
      }
   }


    render(){
       return(
          <Mycomponent data={this.props.data}/>
      )
  }
}
```

Comment: unfortunately, its still the same.

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate),

> `getDerivedStateFromProps` is invoked right before calling the render method, both on the initial mount and on subsequent updates. It should return an object to update the state, or null to update nothing.

You must use this method,

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState){
   if(nextProps.someValue!==prevState.someValue){
     //do something
  }
  else return null;
}
```